# Pusher receive the data but not in the Echo callback function (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo, laravel-9

I am using laravel and pusher for in-app notification . What I did is create account in the pusher and do the congifration like this.

bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Pusher.logToConsole = true;
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true
});
```

Events/Comment.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Comment implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $username;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($username)
    {
        //
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->message  = "{$username} liked your status";
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        // return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
        return new Channel('comments-channal');
    }
}
```

script.js

```
$(function() {
            
            const Http = window.axios;
            const Echo = window.Echo;
           
            let channal = Echo.channel('comments-channel');
            channal.listen('Comment', function(data) {
                alert(data);
                console.log(data)
            })
        })
```

in the controller

```
Comment::dispatch('fatima');
```

Then I got the API message in Pusher debug console but in my console I got this

```
Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":{},"channel":"comments-channel"}
Pusher : No callbacks on comments-channel for pusher:subscription_succeeded
```

FYI I double sheck the `.env` for `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher`

If there is any help I will be very thankful .

Answer (score 0):

To your Comment broadcast Class You could format your data using this function:

```
 public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['username' => $this->username,'message'=>$this->message];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping , but the problem still there . also in the console I see this message ``` Pusher : Connecting : {"transport":"xhr_streaming","url":"https://sockjs-us3.pusher.com:443/pusher/app/926be69fa323dd8af3bd?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1"} ```

Comment: channal.listen('Comment', function(event) {
                alert(event.data);
                console.log(event.data)
            })

Comment: no still not working :(

Comment: new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,cluster:'ap1'
});

Comment: You should add your cluster type .... asian american . . . .

Comment: check your pusher dashboard

Comment: I did in the .env file MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"  | PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=us3

Comment: public function broadcastOn()
    {
        // return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
        return new Channel('comments-channal'); ///????????? check channel name
    }

Comment: should be 'comments-channel'

Comment: Yes , sorry for not notice this .  I did  change it but the problem still the same

Comment: check your broadcast route file

Comment: I dont know were exactliy do you mean in the routes channels ?

Comment: Yes. I Use ionic with laravel pusher and it works perfectly. Private and public channels

Comment: I did not add any thing there just the core one .

Comment: Contact me on Twitter. I'll fix your issue remotely. Check my profile